# Yaml script handlers when porting App Engine app to Python 2.7

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, yaml

I'm porting a Python app from 2.5 to 2.7 on App Engine and I've found the script handlers don't work the same for WSGI endpoints. Specifically, when my endpoint application is defined in a sub-directory, the yaml fails to parse.

```
- url: /crawl/route/.*
  script: crawl/crawler.app
  login: admin
```

In Python 2.5 that ".app" extension was ".py"

This works if the script definition does not have a sub-directory. In fact, all app scripts in the root directory work and all app scripts in a sub-directory fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a path, it's a python object, so use

```
script: crawl.crawler.app
```